# How do I log my Selenium actions into example.metadata[:extra_failure_lines]?

Tags: ruby, logging, selenium-webdriver, rspec, capybara

RSpec 3.4.0 has `example.metadata[:extra_failure_lines]` thing that is to be printed on failure. How do I log Selenium/Capybara actions into it?

```
RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before do |example|
    example.metadata[:extra_failure_lines] = []
  end
end

Capybara::DSL.module_eval do
  alias :old_visit :visit
  def visit path
    example.metadata[:extra_failure_lines] << "visit #{path}"
    old_visit path
  end
end
```

This will fail because `Capybara::DSL` doesn't know about `example`.

Answer (score 0):

I've exposed the `example` as RSpec static module variable:

```
RSpec.module_eval do
  class << self
    attr_accessor :exposed_example
  end
end

RSpec.configure do |c|
  c.before do |example|
    RSpec.exposed_example = example
    example.metadata[:extra_failure_lines] = []
  end
end

# you may use another approaches of monkeypatching
Capybara::DSL.module_eval do
  old = instance_method :visit
  define_method :visit do |path|
    RSpec.exposed_example.metadata[:extra_failure_lines] << "visit #{path.inspect}"
    old.bind(self).(path)
  end
end
```